# toad splits my output

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

When I run a query in Toad, sometimes it splits the output into blocks. How do I get the whole dataset as a single set?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "splits the output into blocks"?  Are you referring to how toad will pull back results in sets of 500 rows at a time?

Comment: @Craig It's actually 20 rows each time. See the new image I added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like the pagesize parameter.  The only problem is that I only know how to turn them all off:

```
set pagesize 0
```

or put them up to every 50000 lines:

```
set pagesize 50000
```

I don't believe Oracle lets you go higher than that.  So I don't know how to get it to print just the first header and nothing else.

Comment: nice. Is there a setting for this in Toad so I don't have to write this every time I have an Editor Window open?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Maybe a question for TOAD support?

Comment: If you get a response either way, would you mind posting it back to this question?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is the SQL*Plus `pagesize` option which default to 24. it can be modified with the command `set pagesize 0` to get rid of it completely.

In SQL*Plus, there is also an option to set this automatically using a `login.sql` or `glogin.sql` script. This functionality also appears to be available in Toad (although I don't have Toad here to test it out on). Further details are [here on this ToadWorld blog post](http://www.toadworld.com/BLOGS/tabid/67/EntryId/172/Toad-and-SQL-Plus-Compatibility.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

it's not exactly toad, it's standard behavior or oracle db. you need to order by some field e.g. to get whole dataset